# How can I reuse a component which has different css aem 6?

Tags: aem

I am working on a page and it has some features that I want to build as one component. But they use different css classes. For eg.

```
<div class="class1 class2">
            <div class="class3">
                <div class="class4">
                    <div class="left">
                        <p class="title">Some content</p>
                        <p class="subtitle">Sub title</p>
                        <p>Paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <p class="title">Title</p>
                        <p class="subtitle">sub title</p>
                        <p>Paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                        <a href="content.html" class="callToAction">See your content</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The content is almost similar but the css classes are pretty much different.
Can I create a component which uses this code and I can just change the css classes(class1, class2 etc) accordingly?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can the author select the style of the component ?

Comment: No. And can't include that in a dialog.

Comment: Also, there are actually many classes which are being changed. So I guess it will not be a good idea to select them by author.

Comment: But can't you give those sets of classes a friendly name and let author select the name ?

Comment: I can try that. But do u think that there is any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You could create a Sightly template, that will output the HTML markup and take some CSS-classes names as input. Then you would extend the base component and each specific component would pass a different class into the template.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have different scripts/jsp for each view and provide an option is dialog box to select one of the scripts/views. Similar approach is followed in the OOTB List component.